# How to reset built-ins in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to reset the `.d.ts` for the global objects? I've this `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": [],
        "target": "es2015",
        "types": [],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "com.adobe.air/*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true
    }
}
```

The current problem is that I get this error 8 times in my IDE with the above `tsconfig.json`:

> Cannot find global type 'Array'.

I've put this in the main script, `src/index.d.ts`:

```
export {};

declare global {
    class Array<T> {
    }
}
```

I'm still getting the error above in my IDE. When I run `tsc` in my project, I get nothing though (I've put stub for other global objects).

Comment: Your empty `lib: []` means you explicitly removed all the types, remove the `lib` entirely then it'll work